# How to search for one phrase in the title and a different phrase in the body of the paper in a single Google Scholar search?

Tags: literature-search, google-scholar

Google Scholar is a very good source of knowledge especially with its advanced search, but the options in the advanced search is either search in the title or in the whole paper. How can I search for a word in a title and a word in the paper itself?

e.g. I want to search for papers that title contains the word "meta analysis" and the body contains "Alexandria". Is there a regular expression to do this?

Comment: I am not sure what this question has to do with "regular expressions". A more suitable term might be "faceted search" (?)

Comment: note on RE, there's a very nice answer on google and regular expressions here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19673/is-there-a-way-to-search-in-google-using-regular-expressions-regex = google can't do regular expressions as running them over so large data would require too much computational power. but I believe on "faceted search" the question has a response.

Comment: @puslet88 It is capable of some regex operations, such as wildcards and ranges.

Comment: @AustinHenley oh wow, thanks, it allowing asterisks (*) is news to me. At least it didn't use to be a case once upon a time. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `intitle:` to search for phrases in the title (no space after the colon) and similarly you can use `intext:` to search in the body.

`intitle:"meta analysis" intext:Alexandria`

Comment: Thank you, can you please show me how to include more words? e.g. the titles contains meta-analysis OR cross-sectional and the text contains Alexandria AND Egypt.

Comment: @ahmedmar You can just use multiple `intext` operators as well as use the typical Google operators for boolean operations (e.g., `OR`). Also, more help about Scholar operators can be found [here](http://libguides.mit.edu/c.php?g=176061&p=1159512).