# How to search for one phrase in the title and a different phrase in the abstract in a single Google Scholar search?

Tags: google-scholar, literature-search

I would like to search for all papers which have both a specific phrase in the title *titlephrase* and also another phrase in the abstract *abstractphrase*.

intitle:"titlephrase" should do the first part but I am stuck on the second and combination.

Note:
[This question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/62290/how-to-search-for-one-phrase-in-the-title-and-a-different-phrase-in-the-body-of) is similar asking for a title and in body search.
[This question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/41443/how-to-use-google-scholar-to-search-key-words-in-abstracts) asks about searching abstracts only but can't be applied here.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE! Of course, I am pleased that you accepted my answer, but since you are new here, I feel I should alert you that it is probably not a good idea to accept an answer immediately just because it sounds good. You can certainly upvote it, but I recommend waiting at least 24 hours or even 48 hours to see if other people might pitch in with better answers. Often once you accept an answer, it demotivates other people from pitching in with other nuances that you might find helpful, or even from disagreeing since they might feel you have already made up your mind. Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks! I had this thought but dismissed it, as it says to accept an answer if it solves your problem, which yours did. Will note for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not what you want to hear, but the answer is that **you cannot conduct abstract-only searches on Google Scholar**. You can see my answer to the question [Google scholar "sort by date" returns articles from last year only?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/67295/google-scholar-sort-by-date-returns-articles-from-last-year-only/67303#67303) for more details (including the comments).

In brief, Google Scholar does not have the functionality to search only in article abstracts. This is most likely because the journals that hold the copyright to the articles that Google Scholar indexes are willing to let Google index their articles so that they can be easily found, but are not willing to let Google provide useful search functionality such as abstract-only searches, otherwise Google Scholar would become a fully-functional free replacement to their commercial services. Without the copyright permissions, Google Scholar cannot have the functionality that you seek.